# How to check IP range and create IF THEN via windows batch file?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I want to create a Windows Batch script (.bat) file.
First of all I need to check the computer IP address and when its in a predefinied range like 172.18.*.* then the script will run toward else the script will go to exit. Please let me know how to made it in the easy way. Thank you.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IP Address"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%b in ('echo %%a') do ( 
        if "%%b.%%c"==" 172.18" (echo do stuff) else echo no match. exiting&exit /b 1
    )
)
```